# Is it possible to re-install sqlite3 on blender 2.81 python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, blender

Question inspired by researching [this issue](https://developer.blender.org/T68243) with `BlenderGIS` and `Blender 2.81`. It seems that there is something wrong with the `sqlite3` library -- looking for a library in a local folder that doesn't exist. The `sqlite3` library is present in the blender interpreter library, but importing it raises an error.

That got me curious about trying to solve the problem by re-installing the `sqlite3` module in blender's python environment. There isn't much documentation on the subject, I guess since its an exceedingly rare thing for someone to want to do. Nonetheless, is it possible?

Comment: Pythons sqlite module is a compiled C library. Binaries contain [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) data that determine where to search for libs. It looks like the osx build may have been configured with an absolute rpath to the dependency lib build folder or dynamic libs were used instead of static. Not sure with osx but *nix you can delete the python folder and it will find the system installed python. So, yes you should be able to build and replace blenders python - not that it is recommended, just make sure you match python versions. Or build your own copy of blender.

Comment: In the terminal use `ldd _sqlite3.cpython-37m-darwin.so` to see the libs it is linked to. Compare the blender install to the one you are replacing it with.